# All the pages are blank

Tags: pages

My friend website blog works well but all the pages show blank pages.

I even look at the source code and I code nothing. It was empty.

What can be causing this when the blog part of WordPress is still working?

He is using WordPress version 3.6.1.

Here are the plugins he uses:

- Akismet
- Categories to Tags Converter Importer
- ePub Export
- Facebook Fanbox Cache Widget
- Google Analytics for WordPress
- Google XML Sitemaps
- Jetpack par WordPress.com
- Quick Chat
- Responsive Add Ons
- Shareaholic | share buttons, analytics, related posts
- WP-Cumulus
- WP Facebook grabber

With the plugins on I get these errors on the blog where does show:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant wp_cumulus_widget - assumed 'wp_cumulus_widget' in /home/---/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-cumulus/wp-cumulus.php on line 375

Notice: register_sidebar_widget est dÃ©prÃ©ciÃ© depuis la version 2.8! Utilisez wp_register_sidebar_widget() Ã  la place. in /home/---/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2919

Notice: register_widget_control est dÃ©prÃ©ciÃ© depuis la version 2.8! Utilisez wp_register_widget_control() Ã  la place. in /home/---/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2919
```

This shows on the blank pages, again with the plugins on:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant wp_cumulus_widget - assumed 'wp_cumulus_widget' in /home/---/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-cumulus/wp-cumulus.php on line 375

Notice: register_sidebar_widget est dÃ©prÃ©ciÃ© depuis la version 2.8! Utilisez wp_register_sidebar_widget() Ã  la place. in /home/---/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2919

Notice: register_widget_control est dÃ©prÃ©ciÃ© depuis la version 2.8! Utilisez wp_register_widget_control() Ã  la place. in /home/---/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2919

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/---/public_html/wp-content/themes/ifeaturepro/page.php on line 15
```

Comment: Update WordPress, disable all plugins, switch to a default theme (Twenty Something), and add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Comment: I am going to try without the plugins and the themes soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the theme of the website.

So the error was here:

```
/home/---/public_html/wp-content/themes/ifeaturepro/page.php on line 15
```

Here is the correction:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/ngr4yya.js"></script>' . "\n";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>';
```

Strange. The person that coded the theme put HTML in the PHP.